# Adobe AIR bring to front - activate() not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I have an adobe desktop AIR app. When I send some data with a local connection, I want the app in front of all the other windows with focus on it.

I tested on a brand new air app with just this code:

```
import flash.display.NativeWindow;
var window:NativeWindow  = stage.nativeWindow;

var aspa = setInterval (activateWin,8000);

function activateWin (){
    trace("Activate window"); 
    window.activate(); 
    clearInterval(aspa);
}
```

And nothing happens. While if I write:

```
window.alwaysInFront=true;
window.alwaysInFront=false;
```

It brings the app to the front, but this command gives no focus to the window.

If I add

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.activate(stage.nativeWindow);
```

This makes the status bar icon blink, but still no focus or front action.

[Reading this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e08.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7dfe), it seems it should work.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I've just use

```
window.activate();
window.alwaysInFront = true;
window.alwaysInFront = false;
```

and it's works fine on windows and mac os

Comment: as said, tested on several computers: if you remove window.activate(); it works the same, but in both cases it have no focus on the window but it just is on the front.